# Where does the hostname in ping reply come from?

Tags: dns, ping

When I ping an IP address from the machine in the same subnet, below is the reply:

```
root@dia11:~# ping B.test.com
PING B.test.com (10.1.128.76) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from A.test.com (10.1.128.76): icmp_seq=1 ttl=62 time=4.85 ms
64 bytes from A.test.com (10.1.128.76): icmp_seq=2 ttl=62 time=5.44 ms
```

However, when I perform the dig for the PTR record for this IP address, a different hostname is shown:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.11.3-1ubuntu1.13-Ubuntu <<>> -x 10.1.128.76
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 42254
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;76.128.1.10.in-addr.arpa.      IN      PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
76.128.1.10.in-addr.arpa. 3600  IN      PTR     B.test.com

;; Query time: 0 msec
;; SERVER: 10.1.129.9#53(10.1.129.9)
;; WHEN: Sat Sep 19 22:41:59 HKT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 87
```

As far as I know, "B.test.com" is the "correct" hostname that the DNS has set.

So I am wondering why "A.test.com" is shown in the ping reply and where does it come from.

Does anyone have an idea on this?

Comment: Later I found out that the host file mapped the IP 10.1.128.76 to A.test.com, while the DNS resolve B.test.com to 10.1.128.76. Resulting in this strange behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes from direct DNS lookup. `ping` asks resolver for IP address of the host  `B.test.com` and gets `10.1.128.76`. `ping` does not use reverse lookup.

I can guess that there are the following records in `test.com` zone.

```
A    A    10.1.128.76
B    A    10.1.128.76
```

or

```
A    A    10.1.128.76
B    CNAME A.example.com.
```

And in the reverse zone 128.1.10.in-addr.arpa

```
76  IN PTR A.example.com.
```

Here is another example (IP V6 results omitted)

```
$host www.google.com
www.google.com has address 172.217.5.100
$dig -x 172.217.5.100

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> -x 172.217.5.100
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 16073
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;100.5.217.172.in-addr.arpa.    IN  PTR

;; ANSWER SECTION:
100.5.217.172.in-addr.arpa. 21457 IN    PTR sfo03s07-in-f4.1e100.net.
100.5.217.172.in-addr.arpa. 21457 IN    PTR sfo03s07-in-f100.1e100.net.

;; Query time: 13 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Sat Sep 19 23:28:06 PDT 2020
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 124
```